# Can't return first value with jq

Tags: json, stream, jq

A command that I run from my terminal return the following:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "env": "prod"
   },
   "created_by": "email@email.com",
   "id": "612",
   "state": "published",
   "version": "0.22.0"
}
{
  "attributes": {
    "env": "prod"
   },
   "created_by": "email@email.com",
   "id": "611",
   "state": "published",
   "version": "0.22.0"
}
```

And I just want to get the "version" from the first object. Theres is a way to do that? Everything I tried with Array returns a error...

Comment: Please update question with the desired output. There are two "version" field in your json, you just want the first version: {"version":"0.22.0"} ? or you want:
`[{"version":"0.22.0"}, {"version":"0.22.0"}]`

Comment: What error do you get? Is it perhaps because this isn't valid JSON, nor a stream of valid JSON objects? JSON doesn't allow trailing commas, like you have here in `"env": "prod",}` If that's the focus of your question please say so.

Comment: Hello, @Joaquin, thanks for you patience! I wanted the {"version":"0.22.0"}, but it seems that Peak's answer returns the value I needed!

Comment: Hello, @Weeble! It used to return something like "jq: error (at <stdin>:19): Cannot index string with number" when I tried something with [0] to get the first value. The case of commas was my mistake when wroting a example, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you've extracted is a stream of JSON objects. You could extract the .version from the first of these by piping the data to:

```
jq -n input.version
```

Comment: It seems to work fine with this! It returns "0.22.0" just like I needed. Thanks for your time!